# How to reset Kudu cached deployment on Azure

Tags: azure, go, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I previously had a Node app on Azure Web App that is now a Go app. Problem is when I deploy I get this from Kudu:

`Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --node --sitePath "D:\home\site\repository"').`

This obviously complains later that no server/app.js file are found.

So I tried generating a deployment script for my app with `azure site deploymentscript --go`.

Even though I have the GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1 in the app's settings it was complaining about dependencies. All my dependencies are vendored in the /vendor folder.

I than set this variable inside the `deploy.cmd` file that were generated by the `azure site deploymentscript` command.

Still it's complaining that one dependencies is not there. Note that now it is searching into the local vendor tree, but the dependencies is there, I can see it in the Github repo and I see it locally as well.

I have other Go apps that deployed just fine with vendored dependencies on Azure, but this one, was a Node app previously is simply not working at all.

I even tried to comment the dependencies getter from the `deploy.cmd`, since all are local this steps is not required. But even that did not work, because the `go build` failed complaining about the dependency not being there. It's on the vendor folder and `GO15VENDOREEXPERIMENT` is set to 1 in the cmd file and in the app application settings.

So what are my option here?

How can I tell Kudu to use a Go default deployment, maybe the one from Azure will work, since my other app do not have local `.deployement` and `deploy.cmd` files.

Edit

I just did a test deploy to a completely new Azure web app, and the app is detected as a Node app by default. I would guess it's due to the presence of a package.json at the root, I also have a main.go that has `package main` as package name.

So maybe it's just the `deploy.cmd` that is generated by `azure site deploymentscript` that is not up-to-date or something? (I updated my verison of the azure-cli just FYI, since at first I did not had the --go flag).

Just for completeness here's the output of Kudu when deploying on a freshly created app, getting same error as the Node one:

`remote: Resolving dependencies
remote: # cd .; git clone https://github.com/org/mypkg D:\local\Temp\8d3397e1e014401\gopath\src\github.com\org\mypkg
remote: Building Go app to produce exe file
remote: Cloning into 'D:\local\Temp\8d3397e1e014401\gopath\src\github.com\org\mypkg'...
remote: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Bad file descriptor
remote: package github.com/org/pkg/lib: exit status 128
remote: azureapp\main.go:3:8: cannot find package "github.com/org/pkg/lib" in any of:
remote:         D:\local\Temp\8d3397e1e014401\gopath\src\azureapp\vendor\github.com\org\pkg\lib (vendor tree)
remote: Copy files for deployment
remote:         D:\Program Files\Go\1.5.3\src\github.com\org\pkg\lib (from $GOROOT)
remote:         D:\local\Temp\8d3397e1e014401\gopath\src\github.com\org\pkg\lib (from $GOPATH)
remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
remote: Could Not Find D:\home\site\repository\azureapp.exe
remote: Copy web.config
remote: web.config already existed. Skip
remote: Finished successfully.
remote: Running post deployment command(s)...
remote: Deployment successful.`

Why is it trying to clone the library, this line here [second line] is probably what cause the entire issue:

`remote: # cd .; git clone https://github.com/org/mypkg`

Why if `SET GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1` is set it is trying to clone the dependency? It's not doing that on my other Go app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what caused that state, but try the following:

- Go to [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)
- Got into the `D:\home\site\deployments\tools` folder
- Delete `deploy.cmd` and `deploymentCacheKey`
- Try depoying

Comment: When receiving this the first time I did a rm -rf on deployments and on repository, I just tried to deploy on a fresh web app and I'm getting same error, for some reasons the dependencies are not seen from the /vendor folder

Comment: it is trying to clone the vendored dependency remote: # cd .; git clone https://github.com/org/mypkg  . Even if GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1 I don't get what I'm doing wrong

Comment: can you try to clean up the cache as what David mention and try again?  also will be good to do a diff of all the environment variable since you mention you have another Go app is working, to see what are the difference. (to get environment variable, simple run "set" on debug console)

Comment: Xiaomin Wu yes I removed cache in Tools, did the SET to make sure GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT was there (it is), removed .deployment/deploy.cmd from local than push. Kudu is automatically seeing a Nodejs deployment (probably due to package.json, so it's not seeing the main.go or take Node by default in order of importance]. So I re-cleared the cache on deployments/Tools, removed web.config on server, added the deploy.cmd from deployments/tools from a working Go app I have on Azure, so I guess the issue was that even after a reset the deploymentCacheKey was always reset to a Node deploy

Comment: right, if you have package.json file there, nodejs project resolver will be take over than go project resolver, since go project resolver was introduced after nodejs project resolver.