# Azure function deployed from package updates not visible

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions

I'm deploying an azure function app from package (using this guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package) - this deploys correctly.  Yet I can't seem to get an update deployed.  Even after I upload a new package, changes are not picked up by azure function app. I tried stopping/starting the app to no avail.

How can I force it to pick up changes?

Comment: The documentation says it requires a restart, is it not working ? do you have all the app settings configured on the portal ???

Comment: Everything is configured. Restart done multiple times - still not picking up changes.

Comment: What's the value of `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`? `1` or sas url?

Comment: @JerryLiu It is SAS url. It deployed correctly the first time round.

Comment: @AleksG Have updated my answer, try cli command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all efforts, the only thing I really determined was that you need to restart - and then wait. About 15-20 minutes after restart the changes were automagically there.

Comment: restart what? Azure function app? right

Comment: @itmannz yes, restart  azure function app

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue with a newly deployed function using function v3, so this still seems to be an issue.

**Short answer:**
Remove the .zip in `D:\home\data\SitePackages` and then redeploy and your changes will get picked up.

**Long answer**

My setup is using ZIP deployment and `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1`.

It helps to know what happens when you use ZIP deployment:

1. The zip file is *not* written to wwwroot of your site, but instead to `D:\home\data\SitePackages` (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package)
2. Then the contents of the zip file is mounted to `D:\home\site\wwwroot` and run from there.

For some reason, the .zip in `D:\home\data\SitePackages` was not being replaced, it was still the old version. To fix that, I used the Console of the App Service to delete the file before redeploying.

1. Navigate to your App Service function and open the Console (under Development tools section)
2. Run `cd D:\home\data\SitePackages` and then `ls` to see the files in the folder.
3. Run a `rm` command to remove both the zip and text file.
4. Redeploy your function, and you will see that changes are picked up.

Answer (score 2):

We had a very weird problem using Azure Function App Deploy from Azure DevOps.

This worked perfectly until we one day made some code changes to the Azure Function that worked locally but not on our dev server. We started looking at the `.zip` file and the release pipeline but everything looked good here. We could also see that nothing had changed in our `azure-pipelines.yml` or release pipeline:

[image]

Git command: `git log -p azure-pipelines.yml`

[image]

For releases we used the `Azure Functions` task by Microsoft Corporation.

[image]

Looking at the release logs everything seemed good as well:

[image]

We then logged in to Kudu (Advanced Tools) and used powershell to look at the files deployed.

```
https://<your-function>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell
```

Running the command `dir D:\home\site\wwwroot` we could see that the files had not been updated and when we looked at `dir D:\home\data\SitePackages` we could not see a new .zip file either.

[image]

Confirmed wrong `.zip` by running the command `Get-Content D:\home\data\SitePackages\packagename.txt` to see which `.zip` is being used.

[image]

Then wen't back to Azure DevOps and tried to create a new release but the files still did not update. Then I tried to clone the `Azure Function App Deploy` step that had previously worked and disabled the other one. Tried a new release and now everything worked.

[image]

[image]

I think this must be a Microsoft bug since we did not really change any values at all. Hope this can help someone else and that Microsoft fixes this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you replace old package using new one with the same package name(to leverage the same sas url), make sure the old one is overwritten. And you have to click the refresh button next to Function app to sync triggers along with the changes.

**Update**

I recommend using the publish command(`func azure functionapp publish <functionAppName>`) provided by Azure Function Core Tools(Cli). V2 Cli benefits from Run from package as well and automates the whole process for us(zip the folder, upload, create app setting, sync triggers).

The command get publishing info(username, password for deployment) first, then

1. Archives function project.
2. Uploads zip file(name is in the format of `UTCTime-GUID`.zip) to `function-releases` container in Storage account specified by `AzureWebJobsStorage` app setting.
3. Create an app setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP`(original name of `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`, both work) with SAS Url.
4. Sync triggers to pick up changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to deploy with new JAR/ZIP to function-app , the changes will be reflected within 1-2 mins 
* Make sure that you are using correct value for **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE**
* Download the content from console and check whether its same or not

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after changing the deployment to use `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`. I think the problem is that it is using the cached deployment tool, so it's using the previous deployment script, not a new one when you change how you want it to deploy.

If you look at the deploy log in azure devops there is a link to the deploy log in the kudu interface:
[image]

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35516470/1585) which explains how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following from VS Code command palette:
**Python: Clear Cache and Reload Window**

And then re-deploy. This will work definitely. If you are using other language than Python there must be some similar prompt to reload. if you need any help comment here, I will try to answer them in best of my capability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I don't have VS Code nor VS.  I'm developing using another set of tools and package separately.

Comment: Further, I can't rely on anything manual - the whole process of building and deploying is automated using Jenkins on Linux.